# Find a set of scalar parametric equations.

Tags: calculus

Find a set of scalar parametric equations for the
line that satisfies the given conditions.

Passes through $P(x0, y0, z0)$ and $Q(x1, y1, z1)$.

Since they are points I assume that you have to subtract $Q-P$. Which would give you $x1-x0 + y1-y0 + z1- z0$ does this give you the set of points required for this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q-P = (x_1 - x_0, y_1 - y_0, z_1-z_0)$.  You don't add the components.

What you really want though is a vector pointing from the point P to the point $Q$.  The way we find that is first to know that $\overrightarrow {OP} = x_0i + y_0j + z_0k$ and $\overrightarrow {OQ} = x_1i + y_1j + z_1k$.  Then $$\overrightarrow {PQ} = \overrightarrow {OQ} - \overrightarrow {OP} = (x_1 - x_0)i + (y_1 - y_0)j + (z_1-z_0)k$$

Can you see where to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R(x,y,z)$ be a point of the line in which Point $P\left(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}\right)$ and $Q\left(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1}\right)$ Lies

Then Here $\bf{Direction\; ratio }$ of $\bf{PR}$ is $$<x-x_{0},y-y_{0},z-z_{0}>$$

and Here $\bf{Direction\; ratio }$ of $\bf{PQ}$ is $$<x_{1}-x_{0},y_{1}-y_{0},z_{1}-z_{0}>$$

Now Here Line $\bf{PR}$ is parallel to $\bf{PQ}$

So $\bf{Direction \; Ratio}$ of these lines are proportional.

So $$\displaystyle \frac{x-x_{0}}{x_{1}-x_{0}} = \frac{y-y_{0}}{y_{1}-y_{0}} = \frac{z-z_{0}}{z_{1}-z_{0}} = \lambda$$